# Shouldn't tags always have descriptions so we can know which tags to use?

Tags: discussion, tags

When I looked through all the tags on this side to subscribe to some of them, I found that alot of them does not have any descriptions at all. Considering you have a very strict policy on quality of questions, answers and so forth, it becomes a bit confusing.

Should it not be a requirement to have a clear description on tags, So users can tag the best way possible?

I dont think users can tag questions as this community wants them to, when it's unclear what tags should be used for what. And it ends up giving the admins a lot of unneccesary work.

I think that is another reason why there are so many questions tagged with dnd 4e. It is a safe tag to use, which results in, that people use it, for questions that require other tags to cover the content of it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the guy who removed those tags, and you've got a great question about tag wikis. First, though, a clarifying point which will come back to be relevant to the topic at hand: I'm not an appointed administrator or moderator. Stack Exchange expects its citizens to help moderate the site with [tools](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) gained via participation (measured by [reputation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)). You've unlocked a few of those already! Anyway, my edits aren't binding or magically correct, just my own best attempts to help out.

Now to your main question, about tags and their wikis.

> Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>   Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you. [[source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)]

This means that tags should be related to the primary drive of the question; nearly every question on the whole site could be tagged [players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/players), but very few would be usefully defined by that tag, which would render the [players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/players) tag useless and pointless. A lot of questions do only have a single tag (usually a system tag like [dnd-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e)) because there isn't any other tag which could usefully be applied to them. (Maybe one needs to be made; see below.)

As for tagging to indicate the kind of answer you want to get--it's something we're still working the bugs out of, and you stumbled over it in the meantime. That's the other thing about tags: they're "emergent," meaning that we don't make them up in anticipation of a need, we make them when the need emerges.

This is very important to the site's health and dynamics for a number of experience-based reasons, but it also relates directly to your concern about tag wikis: tag definitions don't appear automagically, somebody has to write them. When a tag wiki looks weak (or doesn't exist at all), it's waiting for someone to write it or improve it. That somebody could be you!

All registered users can submit edits for tag wikis (until you hit a certain rep threshold the edits have to be approved by other users before they go public, but you get bonus rep every time that happens!). It's not something a lot of our citizens are necessarily really active in doing (I'm guilty of that myself), partly because system-specific tag wikis need experts in that system, while system-agnostic tag wikis need to be kept general enough that they apply to multiple systems without being so vague that they don't define anything useful.

Many of our tag wikis are, as you've noticed, sadly bare. This is a challenge we should rise to! Thanks for reminding us of it, and I hope you'll be part of the effort to improve our tag wikis. It's part of the whole Stack Exchange ethos, where *all* citizens work to improve the site behind the scenes as well as by creating front-page content.

Comment: Thank you for telling me, I was not aware that I could ad descriptions to tags. I just think it's an essential concern, because each time a question is tagged, people who subscribed to that certain tag, gets an email about the questions. Im gonna spend some time studying this site some more, and then I will try to see if I can do anything about the tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/36521/revisions), first, look at the revision history.

Second, we require questions about systems be tagged with that system in question. If you look at the revision history, BESW commented: "tags describe questions, not answers, with an eye to future look-up; most tags on this are tangential to the question itself"

If you object, you are welcome to revert the question.

Comment: Okay that i missed, fair enough, apologies. But that still leaves me with two thoughts. I actually thought you where supposed to tag the type of answers you wanted...and a part of this question, is still about why its not a requirement to add a description to tags to make it clear what they are used for.

Comment: @Anna tag wikis (the descriptions you're referring to) are recommended, but not required, because they take a bit of work to do well. But anyone can edit them, so feel free if you have some time and understand a tag well enough to document it's use.